# Custom layout for push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using Parse.com to send push notifications, and I created a custom layout for the notifications.

To do that, I extended the class `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` like this:

```
public class PushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .addExtras(intent.getExtras())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.push_icon))
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100})
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .build();

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        String title = "";
        String message = "";
        String color = "";

        try {
            json = new JSONObject(extras.getString("com.parse.Data"));
            title = json.getString("alert");
            message = json.getString("message");
            color = json.getString("color");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("PushBroadcastReceiver", "Could not parse notification JSON:\n" + extras.getString("com.parse.Data"));
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.message, message);
        contentView.setInt(R.id.color, "setBackgroundColor", Color.parseColor(color));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            notification.bigContentView = contentView;
        } else {
            notification.contentView = contentView;
        }

        return notification;
    }
}
```

Issue update:

The layout works for the first push notification sent. Whenever the device receives another notification, the previous will be "refreshed", and the layout will be the default, rather than the custom one.

What do I need to do in order to have the same layout all the time?

Comment: is your receiver registered in the manifest?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK yes, with RECEIVE, OPEN and DELETE intent filters